# I want different authentication system for normal user and admin user in Django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

I create a website where there is a normal user and admin. They both have different log in system.But the problem is when a user logged in as a user, he also logged in into admin page. Also when a admin logged in, he also logged in into user page.

```
def userlogin(request):
    error = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u = request.POST['emailid']
        p = request.POST['pwd']
        user = authenticate(username=u, password=p)
        try:
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                error = "no"
                return redirect(profile)
            else:
                error = "yes"
        except:
            error = "yes"
    return render(request, 'login.html', locals())
```

```
def login_admin(request):
    error = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u = request.POST['uname']
        p = request.POST['pwd']
        user = authenticate(username=u, password=p)
        try:
            if user.is_staff:
                login(request, user)
                error = "no"
            else:
                error ="yes"
        except:
            error = "yes"
    return render(request,'login_admin.html', locals())
```

This model is used for normal user signup

```
class Signup(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/img", default="")
    upvotesuser = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to achive different authentication system for user and also for admin.

Comment: How do you create your users?

Comment: I used a model signup to create normal user and admins are super user

Answer (score 0):

Make some roles explicitly in SignUp model as follows as Django provides that too:

1. admin
2. staff
3. simple user/regular user

Define the role of each user in the SignUp model. If a regular user is logged in it will definitely be filtered from the signUp model and that will return him/her as a regular/simple user.

Comment: Can you provide a demo code or references

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create another model for signup
You can easily check the current user permissions
E.g

- is_admin
- is_staff
- is_superuser
  Then redirect depending on the permisions